# Keep Calm Crown Copyright

Tags: copyright

Can I use the "Keep Calm Crown" in a commercial design or is there any copyright?

[image: crown]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question.  Employ a lawyer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Calm_and_Carry_On#Trademark_claims) is unclear on the eventual outcome, but 'Keep Calm & Carry on Ltd' claim the slogan as a [community trade mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_trade_mark).

Whether they can enforce a takedown order for the actual logo I don't think has yet been tried in the courts.